# Understanding Flutter's SchedulerBinding in the context of an animated timeline

Tags: flutter, animation, dart, android-animation

I'm trying to understand the part of this code below that uses `SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback(beginFrame);`. `beginFrame` is listed in the other code block below.

The code comes from [here](https://github.com/2d-inc/HistoryOfEverything/blob/master/app/lib/timeline/timeline.dart#L771), which is an **animated timeline for Flutter**. I don't expect anyone to read all this, obviously. But given some context, can you understand what for it is being used?

Context: this part of the code is inside a function called `setViewport`. The viewport of a timeline is simply the visible part of that timeline. So, once a viewport is set (a `start` and `end` point in the timeline are given), it ends animating something in the timeline. You can see that in the process of doing it, it calls `SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback`, which is what I want to know what is used for. I obviously went into the [page  for SchedulerBinding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding-mixin.html) but the explanation is so generic that I don't have an idea what it is used for.

```
    if (!animate) {
      _renderStart = start;
      _renderEnd = end;
      advance(0.0, false);
      if (onNeedPaint != null) {
        onNeedPaint();
      }
    } else if (!_isFrameScheduled) {
      _isFrameScheduled = true;
      _lastFrameTime = 0.0;
      SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback(beginFrame);
    }
```

Here's beginFrame:

```
  /// Make sure that all the visible assets are being rendered and advanced
  /// according to the current state of the timeline.
  void beginFrame(Duration timeStamp) {
    _isFrameScheduled = false;
    final double t =
        timeStamp.inMicroseconds / Duration.microsecondsPerMillisecond / 1000.0;
    if (_lastFrameTime == 0.0) {
      _lastFrameTime = t;
      _isFrameScheduled = true;
      SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback(beginFrame);
      return;
    }

    double elapsed = t - _lastFrameTime;
    _lastFrameTime = t;

    if (!advance(elapsed, true) && !_isFrameScheduled) {
      _isFrameScheduled = true;
      SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback(beginFrame);
    }

    if (onNeedPaint != null) {
      onNeedPaint();
    }
  }
```

Comment: it adds a callback to be executed in the beginning of the next frame - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart#L1020 for more info

Answer (score 1):

According to the project README, it's used to keep the Flare animations in sync:

"To have the animation reproduce correctly, it's also necessary to call advance(elapsed) on the current FlutterActor each frame. Moreover, the current ActorAnimation requires that the function apply(time) is called on it to display it's correct interpolated values.
This is all made possible by relying on Flutter's SchedulerBinding.scheduleFrameCallback()."